# Jenkinsfile switch variable wrongly applied

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've an issue while using SWITCH on a Jenkinsfile. When the PR is done the pipeline is started using println I see the CHANGE_TARGET is correct to match the CASE condition, however it apply master and all variables are set using the MASTER case values.

the first println return:

> The build ENV is test | PR Title: XXX

code example:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {

    stage('Setup Variables') {
      steps {
        script {
          switch(env.CHANGE_TARGET) {
            case 'test':
              API_Cluster = 'cluster-api'
              API_Service = 'api'
              API_DockerFile = 'api-test'
              ECR_ImageTag = 'XXX'
            case 'qa':
              API_Cluster = 'cluster-api'
              API_Service = 'api'
              API_DockerFile = 'api-qa'
              ECR_ImageTag = 'XXX'
            case 'master':
              API_Cluster = 'cluster-api'
              API_Service = 'api'
              API_DockerFile = 'api-prod'
              ECR_ImageTag = 'XXX'
            default:
              println "Branch name was not set!"
              break;
          }
        }
      }

    }

    stage('Build Details') {
      steps {
        println("The build ENV is " + CHANGE_TARGET + " | " + "PR Title: " + CHANGE_TITLE)
        println("Services:" + API_Service + " | " + WEB_Service)
      }
    }

    stage('Build API') {
      steps {
        sh """docker build --rm --tag api:${ECR_ImageTag} -f ${API_DockerFile} ."""
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `break` at the end of every case. When there is no `break`, Groovy continues and runs the code from the remaining cases.

```
switch(env.CHANGE_TARGET) {
   case 'test':
      API_Cluster = 'cluster-api'
      API_Service = 'api'
      API_DockerFile = 'api-test'
      ECR_ImageTag = 'XXX'
      break

   case 'qa':
      API_Cluster = 'cluster-api'
      API_Service = 'api'
      API_DockerFile = 'api-qa'
      ECR_ImageTag = 'XXX'
      break

   case 'master':
      API_Cluster = 'cluster-api'
      API_Service = 'api'
      API_DockerFile = 'api-prod'
      ECR_ImageTag = 'XXX'
      break

   default:
      println "Branch name was not set!"
      break;
 }
```

Comment: Absolutely right! totally missed it in the case and only added into the default choice. Thanks!